# Calculating number of different colored pixels in multiple polygons at once

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I have a raster with 17 different colors. I need to find the count of pixels in each colour. I could use Zonal statistics for one polygon but I have to find the count in multiple polygons at once. How can I accomplish that in QGIS?

Comment: Is your color defined as RGB composite? Also it would be nice if you can expound how you used Zonal statistics tool for one polygon. It will give us good starting point.

Comment: Hello Kazuhito, sorry for my delay in response. I could use zonal statistics for only a single polygon but that single polygon, in my case, has 66 sub-polygons. Now, I have to assess different colors in each of 66 polygons at once. Can you help me?